# format string inside curly brackets are replaced with one curly brackets

Tags: python, string, format

I'm trying to parse a `string` with `format-string`,

the **string structure** is looks like this:

`<link href="assets/img/favicon.png" rel="icon">`

and the solution might looks like this -

`<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/img/apple-touch-icon.png') }}" rel="apple-touch-icon">`

So my `format-string` based solution is -

`"{0}{1}=\"**{{** url_for('static', filename='**{2}**') **}}**{3}".format(tag_start, href_src_param, file_name, tag_end)`

but the second `param` is breaking the entire `parse line`, does anyone knows how to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Thanks to Lidor-Dublin I got this [link](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) and found there the way to solve this problem, so my code now has been changed:
[image]
also noticed that f (fast) string is better than format()